# pyODBC insert failing silently

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm using python 3.4 (ActiveState) and pyodbc 3.0.7 on a Windows 7 box to connect to a SQL Server 2008 RC2 database running on Window NT 6.1.

The problem I'm having is that the code below fails silently.  No changes are made to the database.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(local);DATABASE=Kerb;UID=sa;PWD=password", autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [My].[Sample] (Case) VALUES (1);''')
```

I've also attempted to force the insert with a commit statement (which, unless I'm mistaken, shouldn't be necessary due to the autocommit=True), this also fails with no output.

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [My].[Sample] (Case) VALUES (1);''')
cursor.commit()
```

So my solution so far has been to add a sleep, which has solved the problem.  But I worry about implementing this solution in production as it doesn't take into account network lag, etc.

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO [My].[Sample] (Case) VALUES (1);''')
time.sleep(1)
```

I believe my question may be related to:
[pyODBC and SQL Server 2008 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935933/pyodbc-and-sql-server-2008-and-python-3)

If anyone has any ideas for further debugging or has documentation regarding this bit of asynchronous behavior I would love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the actual INSERT statement a column(s) definition you're working with? The connection string (also with which driver and operating system you're using) would be helpful as well. It makes a fairly big difference, for example, if you're on Linux whether you're using the FreeTDS driver or the MS ODBC for RedHat driver. Thanks.

Comment: @FlipperPA, absolutely.  I've added more details on the software I'm using as well as the insert I'm trying to perform.  Let me know if you think anything else might help someone recognize the problem.

Comment: Aha! We were having issues with the 3.0.7 pyodbc driver under Python 3.4.x. Two things to try: (1) try the new 3.0.10 pyodbc driver with: `pip uninstall pyodbc && pip install pyodbc==3.0.10` or (2) try with Python 3.3.x. I'd recommend (1), which works for me on 3.4.x (I'm building a new vagrant image with 3.4 and pyodbc 3.0.10 for work to replace the 3.3 / 3.0.7 image devs use now). Let me know if it works and I'll make this an "official answer."

Comment: I haven't had any luck with pyodbc 3.0.10. It still requires a time.sleep(1) to properly execute the query.  I'm going to wipe out python 3.4 and install 3.3. I'll report back. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @FlipperPA haven't had any luck with 3.3 or 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears that PyODBC cannot execute insert statements without the use of a timeout.  I have started using PyMSSQL and the timeout is no longer required for a successful commit.